# Why does the subscript operator at any index on a function always returns 1 in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

This is my code. It seems that f[i] returns 1 at any value of i.

```
int f(int x) { return 203; }

int main(){
  cout<<f[0]<<' '<<f[21]<<' 'f[-1];//= 1 1 1
  return 0;
}
```

Using the warning thrown by the compiler I understand that this is a pointer but it doesn't seem to behave like one.

```
f[-2](1) // = 203, good
f[32](1) // Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 6.731 s
```

EDIT: I use the g++ compiler with the c++ 14 flag.

Comment: Clang doesn't compile this. I'm inclined to say it's not valid C++.

Comment: What compiler? I get the error *"Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type"* (MSVC)

Comment: My GCC says `error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic`. You should specify your compiler.

Comment: It seems like it isn't valid c++ after all. It strangely compiles and even works on the g++ compiler.

Comment: Well, that just tells me that I should never ever use g++ because it's not just bad, it's horribly bad when it accepts as correct and compiles clearly ill-formed and non-compliant code.

Comment: The issue I have with g++ is that by default, it allows all sorts of "extensions" to be used, instead of only having those extensions turned on by a compiler switch.  It makes newbie programmers believe they are writing valid C++ code when they're not.

Comment: @Casey *"I should never ever use g++"* Maybe never use it without `-std=c++?? -pedantic-errors`?

Comment: @Casey it's sort of easy to say that now, when clang exists, but there were **decades** of time before, when GCC was basically the only cheap+libre option, unless you were willing to pay thousands of dollars for commercial compiler. I definitely like clang a lot and it seems today a bit superior to g++, but maybe remind yourself the gcc was a pioneer where nobody else did want to go, and it's the main reason why there exists like maybe half of the good stuff you use daily. :)

Comment: @Casey - *All* compilers accept old and crappy code by default, because it saves them from complaints about breaking code that "has always worked". People who know that there are better versions of the language standard, are also competent enough to select a few compile options. Most newbies are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a GCC extension:

> #### [6.23 Arithmetic on `void`- and Function-Pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html)
>
> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a `void` or of a function as 1.
>
> A consequence of this is that `sizeof` is also allowed on `void` and on function types, and returns 1.

Resulting pointers to non-existent functions, if called, would most likely crash or produce weird results.

---

> It seems that `f[i]` returns `1` at any value of `i`.

That's a well-known behaviour of `cout`. It prints all non-zero function pointers as `1`, because there is no proper overload of `operator<<` for them, and `operator<<(bool)` gets chosen as a most suitable overload.

(`f[i]` is a function rather than a function pointer, but it decays to a pointer in this case.)